# Trying to fill State names in another column

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, autofill

I currently have a spreadsheet that has all of the names of cities in column A like so:

```
Dallas, TX
New York, NY
Miami, FL
```

What I would like to do is extract the states from this first column and place them in column B.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
Sub StateFill()

Dim x As Long
For x = 1 To 65536
    If InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("$A$" & x), ", AL") Then
        Sheet1.Range("$B$" & x) = Sheet1.Range("$B$" & x) & "AL"
    End If
Next

For x = 1 To 65536
    If InStr(1, Sheet1_metro.Range("$A$" & x), ", AK") Then
        Sheet1.Range("$B$" & x) = Sheet1.Range("$B$" & x) & "AK"
    End If
Next

...

For x = 1 To 65536
    If InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("$A$" & x), ", WY") Then
        Sheet1.Range("$B$" & x) = Sheet1.Range("$B$" & x) & "WY"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I'm getting the error 'Runtime Error 424: Object Required' and not sure what's going wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In B1 put the following formula `=Right(A1,2)` and copy down.  It will take the last two characters in the corresponding A.

Answer (score 1):

This:

`Sheet1_metro.Range`

Is not defined in the sub.

Here is an alternative approach:

```
Sub StateFill()
    Dim x As Long, N As Long

    With Sheet1
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 1 To N
            If Right(.Range("$A$" & x), 4) Like ", [A-Z][A-Z]" Then
                .Range("$B$" & x) = .Range("$B$" & x) & Right(.Range("$A$" & x), 2)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go like follows:

```
Sub main()
    With Sheet1
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .Offset(,1).Value = .Value
            .Offset(,1).Replace What:="*, ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False 
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Nick, did you try this?